# Slider Revolution Responsive jQuery Slider - embeded YouTube breaks auto-advance on slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, revolution-slider

When I embed a youtube video in my slider, it breaks the "Auto Advance" to the next slide.  Every other slide advances fine.  It also won't auto play (unless I add to the data-videoattributes &autoplay=1) so autoplay must also be broken.

Here is the html  (The youtube does play fine when youclick on it)

```
           <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="8" data-masterspeed="700" data-delay="9400" data-thumb="../../assets/frontend/pages/img/revolutionslider/thumbs/thumb2.jpg">
          <img src="../../assets/slider_backs/dark_building.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="caption lfl slide_item_left tp-videolayer" 
            data-x="30" 
            data-y="50" 
            data-speed="400" 
            data-start="10" 
            data-autoplay="true"
            data-volume="mute"
        data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="true"
        data-nextslideatend="true"
        data-videoattributes="fs=0&start=0&showinfo=0&frameborder=0&controls=1&rel=0&end=60"
        data-ytid="oHg5SJYRHA0"
        data-videowidth="533"
        data-videoheight="300"

            data-easing="easeOutBack">
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

This works:

```
data-videoattributes="fs=0&start=0&showinfo=0&frameborder=0&controls=1&rel=0&end=60&version=3&enablejsapi=1"
```

Have to add:  &enablejsapi=1

To get it to work.